# Apoyo con carga de datos excel a myslq php

Tags: php, phpexcel

estoy creando un código para cargar los datos de un archivo excel e insertarlos en mysql. pero tengo problemas con la columna de hora.
el archivo excel tiene el formato hora, como muestra la imagen. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he probado usar el tipo dato TIME de mysql pero solo me guarda en todos los registros
la hora con este valor :21:27:50.
este es parte de mi codigo con el que inserto en mi tabla lo que tengo en el archivo excel.

```
$horae= $fields[15]; //no se puede guradr formato hora  
$horae=date('H:i:s');  ///todo lo guarda commom 21:27:50
```

también he probado colocar el tipo varchar para el campo de hora, y al gurdar lo hace de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de verdad agradeciera su ayuda con este problema.
aqui dejo el link de mi proyecto en github

https://github.com/gnavarro82/sistem...da_datos_linde

Comment: El código relevante a la pregunta va en la pregunta, no en un enlace externo.

Answer (score 0):

Usa este Formato 'HH:MM:SS' es el de MYSQL, Tambien puedes enviar la hora con este formato 'HHMMSS', ejemplo '095300'

Recuerda que el campo debe ser tipo TIME

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución considera revisar [answer] para realizar respuestas en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias!